# How do I get $routeParams inside a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a navBar directive and I would like to use $routeParams to determine which link to set to active. I can access $routeParams in controllers with no problem:

```
app.controller('MovieDetailsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $scope.movie = {};
        console.log($routeParams);
    }]);
```

However, I am unable to get any data from $routeParams in my directive:

```
app.directive('navBar', ['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
        console.log($routeParams);
    }]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: put the `$routeParams` onto the scope of the `MovieDetailsController` then access that scope within the directive. Done!

Comment: doesn't that add a dependency between the directve and the controller? I was under the impression Angular standards suggest against such things. Am I wrong?

Comment: To be honest with you, somes the dirty solutions are the easiest and quickest. Depends what your time limits are etc. etc. etc.

Comment: ain't that the truth, brother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like when the directive is initialized $routeParams is not available. If you use the directive like below as in the plunk it should work.

```
app.directive('myDir', ['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
          alert($routeParams.number);
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/joHLLqtsUK3xCAVemmeg?p=preview

Comment: I see that the link function does have access to the routeParams but how do i pass it to my directive's internal controller where my logic exists?

Comment: What do you mean by "directive's internal controller"? Can you give an example?

Comment: nvm, I did some research. I was under the impression all directive logic goes in the directive's controller function. I see now that I need my logic in the link function. Furthermore, I also noticed that what I needed was the $location, not the $routeParams. Thanks for the Plunker example. It helped!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno your research was correct, you should put the logic in the directives controller where ever possible. However the link function is there for a reason and this is one of the cases where it can't be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

try with ui router's `$state.current.name` , it will give you the current `route` in which you are in

Comment: I get `$state is not defined`

Comment: i think you need to inject $state 'angel s'